# Append index dynamically to attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I have this button element:

```
<button v-on:click="changeRecord(element)" v-b-modal.modal-5>Aendern</button>
```

it is generated dynamically inside a v-for loop.
Instead of hard coding the attribute name like above `v-b-modal.modal-5` I want to concatenate it like this:

```
v-b-modal.modal-{{index}}
```

Is there a way to do this?
I'm using vue-cli 3 and bootstrap-vue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used this framework before but looking at the second example [from the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/) I think something like the following should work.

```
<button v-on:click="changeRecord(element)" v-b-modal="`modal-${index}`">Aendern</button>
```

You will need to ensure that the variable `index` is made available when you set up the `v-for`

EDIT: For clarity, the above works because in VueJS the input to a directive is evaluated as an expression. The above example uses backticks string interpolation but the same can be done using pretty much any valid expression like `"'modal-'+index"` or based on some property on the item we are looping over `` "`modal-${item.id}`" ``.

Unlike directives, class or other attributes are interpreted as plain strings unless they are bound using `v-bind` in which case they are treated as expressions. The example in the docs uses a simple string as an input so it's hard to tell from that particular example that it can be used in this way.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Ill accept your answer in a few minutes when its unlocked :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add dynamic attributes like following

```
<p class="text" v-bind="options">{{ message }}</p>
```

Inside the `computed`, define the value for `options`

```
 export default {
  data:()=> {
    return {
      message: 'Hello world!',
      id: 12345
    }
  },
  computed: {
    options() {
      return {
        [`v-b-modal.modal-${this.id}`]: "whatever"
      }
    }
  }
}
```